# Installing an APK from a web page

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have a little page for a program, and the user can click on a link to get the APK.
Nothing strange, I think, but I'd like to force the telefon to install this APK after downloading it.

Right now, the user has to tap on the downloaded APK to install it.

Do you know, if it's possible to just tap on the URL and force Android to download and install the APK?

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. This topic has been discussed many times on here.

Unless you're willing to host your app on google play and have the user click on there to do an over-the-air install of your app through the google play/google+ api sign-on interface.

Or unless your user has a rooted phone with a custom installer from you that he already installed, this is not possible at all.

Comment: how to make this on rooted phone,can you pls explain

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N On a rooted phone, your initial app with the custom installer would need to ask for root permissions from the user. Once your app has been granted those root privileges, it can basically do anything, even do a zero-click install (like this app for instance: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro ). That being said, don't ask me about the exact implementation details. If this is something you're still interested in, you'll have to do your own research on it.